# Limewire API: does it exist?

Tags: api, com

Does anyone know if there is something like a Limewire API? I need to be able to make Limewire download files programmatically.

**EDIT:** It seems Limiwire doesn't have an API. Is there any other Gnutella P2P cliente that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose focusing a little more upon your requirement, you've got the Gnutella downloader service/class/package API thing.

http://wiki.limewire.org/index.php?title=Gnutella_downloader

It allows you to query and download direct to the network.

Then extending that idea - you have jTella, API source for Gnutella network.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtella/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not. Also, unfortunate: the source code is terribly difficult to read/modify. If, however, you're up to the challenge, then you can simply write your own application on top of limewire-core, which is seperate form the GUI.

Comment: Is there any other P2P cliente that does?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a true api - but I found this by googling your title:

http://wiki.limewire.org/index.php?title=Javadocs

Seems to be built in Java. Entire set of packages seem to be there too.

Comment: I also found that, but I need a true API, without the need to recompile Limiwire source code.